# Using IAccessible with Google Chrome returns incomplete tree

Tags: c++, google-chrome, winapi, iaccessible

I'm trying to create a QA automation for Google Chrome, in order to simulate clicks and receive click events on the tab buttons.

I'm using the [*IAccessible* interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318466(v=vs.85).aspx) and [*AccessibleChildren* API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317975(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the full accessible elements tree.

When using AccExplorer 2.0 to view the tree - it looks great (see image at the end).

But my program shows only a partial tree, and the names do not match the ones I see on AccExplorer.

I'm running:

- Chrome 37 beta
- Win 7 64 bit

Any ideas why I can't view the full tree?

Thanks

**This is my program's source (C++) :** [(similar to MSDN example)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317975(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i=0;
    HWND hWndChrome = NULL;
    hWndChrome = (HWND)0x000702c0;
    wcout << L"\n\nChrome_WidgetWin_1 = "<< hex << hWndChrome << "\n--------------------------";

    CComPtr<IAccessible> pAccMain;
    ::AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWndChrome, OBJID_CLIENT, IID_IAccessible, (void**)(&pAccMain));

    WalkTreeWithAccessibleChildren(pAccMain, 0);
    _getch();

    return 0;
}

HRESULT WalkTreeWithAccessibleChildren(__in CComPtr<IAccessible> pAcc, __in int depth)
{
    long childCount = 0;
    long returnCount = 0;

    HRESULT hr = pAcc->get_accChildCount(&childCount);

    if (childCount == 0)
        return S_FALSE;

    CComVariant* pArray = new CComVariant[childCount];
    hr = ::AccessibleChildren(pAcc, 0L, childCount, pArray, &returnCount);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Iterate through children.
    for (int x = 0; x < returnCount; x++)
    {
        CComVariant vtChild = pArray[x];
        // If it's an accessible object, get the IAccessible, and recurse.
        if (vtChild.vt == VT_DISPATCH)
        {
            CComPtr<IDispatch> pDisp = vtChild.pdispVal;
            CComQIPtr<IAccessible> pAccChild = pDisp;
            if (!pAccChild)
                continue;

            // Print current accessible element
            wcout << endl;
            for (int y = 0; y < depth; y++) wcout << L"    ";
            wcout << L"* " << GetName(pAccChild, CHILDID_SELF).data() << L"  |  " << GetRole(pAccChild, CHILDID_SELF).data() << L" (Object)";

            WalkTreeWithAccessibleChildren(pAccChild, depth + 1);       
        }
        // Else it's a child element so we have to call accNavigate on the parent,
        //   and we do not recurse because child elements can't have children.
        else
        {
            // Print current accessible element
            wcout << endl;
            for (int y = 0; y < depth; y++) wcout << L"    ";
            wcout << L"* " << GetName(pAcc, vtChild.lVal).data() << L"  |  " << GetRole(pAcc, vtChild.lVal).data() << " (Child)";
        }
    }
    delete[] pArray;
    return S_OK;
}

wstring GetName(__in CComPtr<IAccessible> pAcc, __in CComVariant varChild)
{
    if (!pAcc)
        return L"";
    CComBSTR bstrName;
    HRESULT hr = pAcc->get_accName(varChild, &bstrName);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return L"";
    if (!bstrName.m_str)
        return L"<NULL>";
    return bstrName.m_str;
}

wstring GetRole(__in CComPtr<IAccessible> pAcc, __in CComVariant varChild)
{
    if (!pAcc)
        return L"";
    CComVariant varRoleID;
    HRESULT hr = pAcc->get_accRole(varChild, &varRoleID);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return L"";
    WCHAR sRoleBuff[1024] = {0};
    hr = ::GetRoleText(varRoleID.lVal, sRoleBuff, 1024);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return L"";
    return sRoleBuff;
}
```

**And this is the console output:**

```
    Chrome_WidgetWin_1 = 000702C0
    --------------------------
    * Chrome Legacy Window  |  window (Object)
        * System  |  menu bar (Object)
        * <NULL>  |  title bar (Object)
            * IME  |  push button (Child)
            * Minimize  |  push button (Child)
            * Maximize  |  push button (Child)
            * Context help  |  push button (Child)
            * Close  |  push button (Child)
        * Application  |  menu bar (Object)
        * Chrome Legacy Window  |  client (Object)
    //  -----> { there should be a big sub-tree here } <----- //
        * Vertical  |  scroll bar (Object)
            * Line up  |  push button (Child)
            * Page up  |  push button (Child)
            * Position  |  indicator (Child)
            * Page down  |  push button (Child)
            * Line down  |  push button (Child)
        * Horizontal  |  scroll bar (Object)
            * Column left  |  push button (Child)
            * Page left  |  push button (Child)
            * Position  |  indicator (Child)
            * Page right  |  push button (Child)
            * Column right  |  push button (Child)
        * <NULL>  |  grip (Object)
```

**Here is an AccExplorer screenshot showing the full tree:** (some nodes are collapsed)
[image: AccExplorer working example]

---

**Edit:**
When Using *OBJID_WINDOW* instead *OBJID_WINDOW* (as in the example, in *AccessibleObjectFromWindow*) - I get a tree with more nodes, but still I can't see the tab elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so after too long, I found the minor little thing that made all the difference...
I forgot to use *CoInitialize()*...

The interesting thing is that without *CoInitialize()* it works, but only **partially**, and no HRESULT indicated this (didn't get anything like CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED).

Anyway - if you use *IAccessible* wihtout *CoInitialize* - expect things not to work properly...